# Share gradle build file with other projects via GIT repository

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to share a `build.gradle` with other projects via a GIT repository (credentials required)?

Simplified `Build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "7.4";
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/checkstyle/")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git), [grgit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit) or [jgit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) to get the file then

```
apply from: 'path/to/file.gradle'
```